# How to use the UIView.hidden property to change visibility of views

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

In my IOS application, I need to show a drop-down menu when the menu button is pressed and hide it when the menu button is pressed again. I tried changing the hidden status to false and true as in the code below however that doesn't seem to work.

```
if (menuButtonActive == false)
{
    menuButtonActive = true;

    DropMenu.Hidden = true;

}
if (menuButtonActive == true)
{
    menuButtonActive = false;
    DropMenu.Hidden = false;
}
```

Thanks to anyone that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be simple

```
menuButtonActive = !menuButtonActive;
DropMenu.Hidden = menuButtonActive;
```

Answer (score 4):

It's just simple, try this:

**In Swift:**

```
yourView.isHidden = true //or false
```

**In Objective-C:**

```
yourView.hidden = YES; //or NO;
```

**In C#:**

```
yourView.Hidden = true; //or false;
```

In your case you are doing it right, but the problem is you are using only `if` in both cases. You have to use `else if` for second `if` condition in order to achieve the desired result.

Otherwise the second `if` condition will be always true and get executed you will see no effect of first `if` block.

**For Your Case:**

It should be like:

```
menuButtonActive = !menuButtonActive
DropMenu.Hidden = menuButtonActive
```

Hope this help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

look at follow code , add a **else**

```
if (menuButtonActive == false)
{
    menuButtonActive = true;

    DropMenu.Hidden = true;

}
else if (menuButtonActive == true)
{
    menuButtonActive = false;
    DropMenu.Hidden = false;
}
```